# Converting markdown to pdf - unreadable fonts

Tags: go

I use https://github.com/mandolyte/mdtopdf to convet makdown int pdf file
but it makes fonts unreadable if they are from non-Latin characters.

For example, source:

> Кто не понимает вашего молчания, едва ли поймет ваши слова.

result:

> ÐšÑ‚Ð¾ Ð½Ðμ Ð¿Ð¾Ð½Ð¸Ð¼Ð°ÐμÑ‚ Ð²Ð°ÑˆÐμÐ³Ð¾ Ð¼Ð¾Ð»Ñ‡Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ñ•, ÐμÐ´Ð²Ð°
>   Ð»Ð¸ Ð¿Ð¾Ð¹Ð¼ÐμÑ‚ Ð²Ð°ÑˆÐ¸ Ñ•Ð»Ð¾Ð²Ð°.

It has a styler options and required font is proved in the project folder

How to fix that?

Comment: That's not a font issue, it's an encoding issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are taking Unicode and treating it as Latin-1 extended ASCII.

For example, UTF-8 as Latin-1 extended ASCII:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    u := "Кто не понимает вашего молчания, едва ли поймет ваши слова"
    fmt.Println(u)
    for _, b := range []byte(u) {
        fmt.Print(string(rune(b)))
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/75c4RCEc92F

Output:

```
Кто не понимает вашего молчания, едва ли поймет ваши слова
ÐÑÐ¾ Ð½Ðµ Ð¿Ð¾Ð½Ð¸Ð¼Ð°ÐµÑ Ð²Ð°ÑÐµÐ³Ð¾ Ð¼Ð¾Ð»ÑÐ°Ð½Ð¸Ñ, ÐµÐ´Ð²Ð° Ð»Ð¸ Ð¿Ð¾Ð¹Ð¼ÐµÑ Ð²Ð°ÑÐ¸ ÑÐ»Ð¾Ð²Ð°
```

Comment: It seems you are right, you could look at the source code.

https://github.com/mandolyte/mdtopdf/blob/master/mdtopdf.go 


`Process(content []byte)`